Firebase cloud messaging - Getting Error: "TypeError: admin.messaging(...).sendEachForMulticast is not a function
I'm working on a Cloud Function that sends push notifications when a document in Firestore is updated. I've adapted this code from a Firebase codelab example. However, I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve.

TypeError: admin.messaging(...).sendEachForMulticast is not a function
at /workspace/index.js:51:49
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

// Import the Firebase SDK for Google Cloud Functions.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Sends notifications to all users when a new message is posted.
exports.sendNotifications = functions.firestore.document('CustomersWithoutBooking/{messageId}').onCreate(
  async (snapshot) => {
    // Notification details.
    const text = snapshot.data().text;
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'TEST',
        body: 'TESTBODY',
      }
    };

    // Get the list of device tokens.
    const allTokensSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('Behandlere').get();
    const tokens = [];
    allTokensSnapshot.forEach((tokenDoc) => {
      tokens.push(tokenDoc.id);
    });

    if (tokens.length > 0) {
      // Send notifications to all tokens using sendEachForMulticast.
      const responses = await admin.messaging().sendEachForMulticast({
        tokens: tokens,
        notification: payload.notification,
      });

      // Cleanup invalid tokens after sending notifications
      await cleanupTokens(responses, tokens);
      functions.logger.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
    }
  }
);

// Cleans up the tokens that are no longer valid.
async function cleanupTokens(response, tokens) {
  const tokensDelete = [];
  response.responses.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      functions.logger.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        const deleteTask = admin.firestore().collection('fcmTokens').doc(tokens[index]).delete();
        tokensDelete.push(deleteTask);
      }
    }
  });
  await Promise.all(tokensDelete);
}

package.json
{
  "name": "friendlychat-codelab",
  "description": "Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions codelab",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~9.9.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "private": true
}


You're using a very old firebase-admin.  The latest version in 12.5.0.

Ahh..  Thank you so much.
